# PyQt and TCP/IP

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

OK, so i have a pretty simple turn based application (game).

Each user sends a request on the server and then wait for response. The important is, that only **ONE** user makes the request on the server (send his actions) and all other users are just waiting, if the server sends them some data, so they must always check (in loop) if something is coming from server.

I´m using the built-in module of python "socket" and the way i manage the clients is this: For every user i create one thread, in which runs infinite loop, until the application ends, which checks for request (if it is the turn of the user) or checks if it got anything to sent to the other users. Now let´s move to Clients. Every client has again one thread with infinite loop, waiting for data from server.

The problem is that the GUI is made in PyQt4.4, where i cant get into the loop of the PyQt itself (although i have seen, that it is possible to do this with twisted, but then i would have to rewrite my code) so i have to use the thread, that means i can use classic python threading library or `QThread`, but `QThread` sadly doesn´t have any Events, which are pretty crucial because i want always wait after the message from the server for the response of the program, so i can send response to the server again. On the other hand, I am not sure, if i can use Thread from threading to emit signals. So which one is the right one to go?

Btw: is actually ok, to run the infinite client and server side loop? Because in every tutorial I have seen, the client close the connection right after he gets his answer.

EDIT:
here´s some of the code

Server side loop for connection with client:

```
while self.running:
        if self.is_on_turn == p and self.reply is not None:
            cmd = conn.recv(1024)
            if cmd == '':    
                conn.close()
                return
            cmd = eval(cmd)
            if self.is_on_turn != p: # User is not on turn
                print "END"
                conn.sendall("END")
            else:
                self.queue.put(cmd)
        ev.wait()   #    Here works another program with the message and decide what to do next
        ev.clear()  #
        conn.sendall(str(self.message))
        if self.reply:
            ev.wait()   #
            ev.clear()  #
            if self.reply:
                r = conn.recv(1024)
                if r == '':    
                    conn.close()
                    return
                self.queue.put(eval(r))
                ev.wait()   #
                ev.clear()  #
            conn.sendall(str(self.message))
    conn.close()
```

Client side loop:

```
def main_loop(self, pipe, conn, e, o):   #e is event, o is bool (whether the client has to answer back to the server)
    is_on_turn = conn.recv(4096)
    pipe.send((is_on_turn))
    while True:
        if is_on_turn == h or o.value and o.value is not None:
            conn.send(str(pipe.recv()))
        pipe.send(eval(conn.recv(4096)))
        e.wait()
        e.clear()
```

The pipe is there, because I made it in multiprocessing at first, there should the emit signal for the PyQt instead, but as I said, I am not sure which approach to use

Comment: You really need to work on your question. Summarize, post some code example, tell us what have you tried so far...

Comment: If you're using PyQt, why not just use [QTcpServer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html) and [QTcpSocket](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the result is, that I have just used  QTcpServer and QTcpSocket as sugessted by ekhumoro, which resulted in much cleaner code and easier management :)